# how to use MEW, (not geth or mist) to use a private key to recover access to some ERC20 tokenss

Tags: recovery

I lost my jaxx backup phrase. I have private keys to two ERC20 tokens (ICN and SALT). I want to use MEW to regain access/link to my tokens on the blockchain. What are the exact steps in MEW to use private key to relink/pair MEW to these tokens. I've looked for an hour at help and googled it. (I'd use JAXX's 'paper wallet transfer' function to do this, but that function is broken/buggy.)  I can only find geth or mist instructions, but i want to simply use MEW for this recovery.

Comment: If you have the private keys for the account(s) holding the token, you should just be able to go to "Send Ether & Tokens" > select Private Key in the list > paste.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think you can import raw key in MEW but you can with geth (personal.importRawKey), if you wouldn't download all the blockchain you can only install geth and make :

```
geth attach <a web socket or http web3 provider like etherscan node's>
```